# Ensure DCHP lease address in certain range on a corporate network

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp

I'm in a corporate network where several AP expose the same SSID: "CorpAP".

I also have two notebooks where one of them is assigned an address in the range `10.105.104.1 - 10.105.111.254`, while the other one gets one in the range `10.105.64.1 - 10.105.71.254`. These notebooks cannot see each other, so I thought I could get them to enter the same range by connecting to the same AP, specifying the BSSID on the connection info:

[image]

But the allocated IP address is still the same on both notebooks.

What can I do to have them both assigned IPs in the same subnet?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "doesn't see". Do you mean the other computer doesn't show up in "Network discovery", or do you mean the other computer isn't pingable / connectable using its IP address?

Comment: Does the Wi-Fi network use WPA-Personal or WPA-Enterprise? If it uses WPA-Enterprise, are both computers connected using the same account? Does the network have any "device health" policies?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding addressing:

- Your DHCP server remembers what lease was given to you, and will continue to give out the same lease until it expires (doesn't get renewed). You can remove the local copy from `/var/lib/NetworkManager/`, but there's no guarantee that this will actually cause a new lease to be issued; the DHCP server might still continue returning the same lease.
- The BSSID does not affect your address assignments. All access points broadcasting the same "CorpAP" ESSID give you access to the *same* network, with the same addresses, the same DHCP server, and so on.
- However, different client devices might be automatically put into different layer-2 networks (VLANs) based on their login information. For example, computer 1 might be automatically put in the "employee" VLAN (across all BSSIDs), while computer 2 might always get on the "guest" VLAN – again, across all BSSIDs. This isn't controlled by your DHCP settings, only by your Wi-Fi login details.

Regarding subnets:

- Being in a different subnet doesn't always mean communication will be impossible (the whole reason of routers is to connect subnets).

  But on the other hand, being in the same subnet doesn't always mean communication will be *possible*, as some Wi-Fi networks (especially 'guest' networks) isolate all client devices making it so that *all* traffic (even same-subnet) goes through the router, and the router's firewall is configured to block it.

Suggestions:

- Contact your IT team. They set the policies, and they manage the address assignment. Find out whether there are any requirements for being connected to the same subnet, and/or for communications between your two devices.

Comment: Thanks. At least this provides more insight on the subject.

Comment: I was able to make the devices see each other -albeit briefly- by spoofing a different MAC. In the end, I worked around this by setting a PAN access point with blueman. The latency sucks but works

Answer (score 0):

The `netmask` will provide what you want. But without additional information I can't be more specific. But in any case, `netmask` is the/your solution.

Comment: in both devices the netmask is set to 255.255.255.248

Comment: Both of the APs?

Comment: yes. But that would only ensure the network is divided evenly in its own segment, however in this case those segments cannot see each other